# Logout doesn't completely logs me off

Tags: support, logout

I log in to stackoverflow using Google account. I then logout by clicking logout link. It then takes me to a page where below message appears:

> Clicking Log Out will clear our cookies and log you out on all
>   devices.

And I click on Logout button provided. After I press that button I am redirected to stackoverflow home page.

All works well till here. But if I open the Google page in the same window by entering URL www.google.co.in, I see that I am still logged into the Google account.

Why is it happening? Why aint I completely logged out after clicking on Logout button?

I am using Mozilla Firefox 23.0.